# Why does QGIS 2.16 have longer load times than 2.8, especially working with tables?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I was previously running an LTR version of QGIS (2.8.9 I think). I installed 2.16 and found that opening tables takes a very long time. Deleting columns in tables now takes hours as opposed to seconds. It also seems to load and delete columns one by one instead of all at once. I tried the 2.14 LTR and am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Does it work better if you disable plugins, especially digitizing plugins?

Comment: I disabled all my plugins and it seems to make no difference.

Comment: @Paul you are right, version 2.16 loading time is much more even in spatial data not only attribute tables

Comment: Can you share an example project including data that opens fast in 2.8 and slowly in 2.16? Would be worth opening a ticket.

Comment: This seems to be the case with any data I load in 2.16. I just tested the E911 Address data for both Maine (http://www.maine.gov/megis/catalog/shps/state/ng911pts.zip) and Vermont in 2.16.2 and it's as slow as ever. Ten minutes ago I deleted two data columns from the Maine address data table as a test. The operation is about halfway done.