# QGIS Desktop 2.14.5 and 2.16 Projects with Multiple Composers Loading Very Slowly

Tags: qgis

I am experiencing a lot of problems with QGIS Desktop versions >= 2.14 when opening  projects with a large number of composers(~100).  It appears that each composer is being loaded into memory when the project is loaded instead of when I open the composers.

The project is large and contains a large number of layers.  It was created using QGIS 2.10. When I load a version of this project with the same layers but no map composers it opens very quickly (roughly 8 seconds).  When I load the version with all composers it takes about 20 minutes for the project to open.

Is there a setting that can be used to change this behavior or should I plan on sticking to older versions of QGIS?

Comment: I can confirm also on 2.18.0 on Windows 10. Same problem. Once the **slow** initial startup has been done, things goes well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no option that would affect this. I'm surprised the project loads faster in older versions so that might be worth opening a ticket for. Otherwise, it would seem worth evaluating if a project with 100 composers makes sense, i.e. is this something that could be solved using the Atlas feature?

I've updated the issue https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10828 to reflect that this still affects master.

Comment: QGIS 2.16 is indeed very long to load and I have some infos from my colleagues of some annoying behaviors I may report if I can duplicate them properly. See here aswell for other user experience : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203621/why-does-qgis-2-16-have-longer-load-times-than-2-8-especially-working-with-tabl?rq=1

Comment: Yes 100 composers is excessive, but that project is the most extreme test case I have.  If I use a different project that contains 17 composers my load time in 2.10 is 43 seconds.  In 2.14.5 it is 93 seconds.  In QGIS 2.14 and above the initial load of map canvas items is very quick, but then each composer is loaded into memory (according to the project load text) which accounts for all of the additional load time.

Comment: Have you checked the QGIS issue tracker if this issue has been reported yet?

Comment: There is an old issue here with a newish comment at the end https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10828, but that is for version 2.8.2.

Comment: Prior to your reply I posted this issue at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15499 since I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to add it to the older report since the bug was initially reported for 2.8.2.